# Step in the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

In my book it states that since $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function that is continuous at $x\in I$ then there must exist a $r>0$ and a constant $K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\lvert t-x \rvert<r, \hspace{5pt}\textrm{and}\hspace{3pt} t\in I \quad\Rightarrow\quad \lvert f(t) \rvert \leq K. 
\end{equation}

How does this come about? Does it follow from the definition of continuity, and if so would you mind explaining how?

Comment: Yes, this is not indeed.

Comment: Informally this is stated as "if a function is continuous at some point then it is bounded in a certain neighborhood of that point".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, there exists $r\gt 0$ such that for all $t$, if $t\in I$ and $|t-x|\lt r$, then $|f(t)-f(x)|\leq 1$.

Therefore $|f(t)|-|f(x)| \leq |f(t)-f(x)|\leq 1$, so $|f(t)|\leq 1+|f(x)|$. Set $K=1+|f(x)|$.

---

Intuitively: if $t$ is sufficiently close to $r$ (and in $I$), then $f(t)$ is close enough to $f(r)$. So all you need to to is pick a $K$ so that things "sufficiently close to $f(r)$" have absolute value less than $K$.